# F12 Network response garbled characters

Tags: python, web, web-crawler

This is my first time to climb such data, I do not know why his data does not show up, using python's chardet library does not work. Is there someone who can help me? Thank you!

I tried to crawl through the data, but the data seems to be garbled

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that's text?

Comment: yes, there's a slider that sends new data each time it pulls down, this is the website I want to crawling: https://arcg.is/1TS0uu, but this is a Chinese website

Comment: That doesn't mean that what you posted is text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't text. Inspecting the response headers of some of those responses shows

> content-type: application/x-protobuf

That's a binary format that can't be parsed without the message specification. It's used as the message format in gRPC.

You can check the [Protocol Buffer Basics: Python](https://protobuf.dev/getting-started/pythontutorial/) tutorial at the Protobuf site to understand how it works.